# Do I have to take mana from my deck or hand when tapping a dual land?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a land card, for example [Stone Quarry](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStone%20Quarry%5d) which reads "{T}: Add {R} or {W}." Do I take the mana from my library or my hand?

Comment: Related: [How do dual lands and their mana work?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/32365/5573)

Comment: Also: Compare Stone Quarry with [Arid Mesa](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=177584) to see how the other effect is worded.

Comment: @Zulan found [Terrain Generator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393873) as an example of "from your hand"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are confusing Lands with Mana, a common beginners' mistake.

Mana is a resource that you use to cast spells; it is not represented by cards; you can not physically see it. When you tap a land, such as a Mountain, you add a red mana to your mana pool, which means you now have 1 red mana to spend.

When you tap a [Stone Quarry](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStone%20Quarry%5d), you choose to either add a red mana to your mana pool, or to add a white mana to your mana pool. Either way you end up with 1 mana in your mana pool. You do not get any land cards from your library or your hand.

Note that tapping a Stone Quarry is very similar to tapping a Mountain. When you tap a Mountain, you are activating an ability that says ""{T}:Add {R}." This ability is just not printed on the card for basic lands; it is instead within the rulebook for all basic lands.

An effect that has you put a land card from your hand or library onto the battlefield would specifically say so:

[Arid Mesa](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArid%20Mesa%5d)'s ability says:

> Search your library for a Mountain or Plains card, put it onto the battlefield, then shuffle your library.

and [Terrain Generator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTerrain%20Generator%5d)'s ability says

> You may put a basic land card from your hand onto the battlefield tapped.

Note that Arid Mesa can't even produce mana, even though it is a land. Lands commonly produce mana, but not all of them do.

Comment: Good answer, but could use [Arid Mesa](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=177584) and [Terrain Generator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393873) as examples of wording for playing lands from library or hand.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion about number of land drops, you might want to change:
"An effect that has you *get (play) a land* card from your hand or library would specifically say so:"
to: "An effect that has you put a land card from your hand or library onto the battlefield would specifically say so:"

Answer (score 16):

[image: Mountain]

Take a look at the old mountains, they had written on them "[image: {T}]: Add [image: {R}] to your mana pool" from 6th edition on they stopped printing that on the card itself, but the rules still include that all lands with the type Mountain tap for [image: {R}], that's all the land does is add red mana when tapped. Lands produce mana, they aren't actually mana themselves. This is covered in the [Comprehensive Rules](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Land)(emphasis mine):

> **305.6** The basic land types are Plains, Island, Swamp, Mountain, and Forest. If an object uses the words "basic land type," it's referring to one of these subtypes. **A land with a basic land type has the intrinsic ability "[image: {T}]: Add [mana symbol]," even if the text box doesn't actually contain that text or the object has no text box.** For Plains, [mana symbol] is [image: {W}]; for Islands, [image: {U}]; for Swamps, [image: {B}]; for Mountains, [image: {R}]; and for Forests, [image: {G}]. See rule 107.4a. See also rule 605, "Mana Abilities."

That's also why the ability to add mana is in brackets on the more recent printings of typed duals like [Sacred Foundry](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSacred%20Foundry%5d) because being a mountain and a plains means it can tap for red or for white, it doesn't need to be explicit on the card, anything in brackets is just there as a reminder.

Comment: I didn't realize this held true for non-basic lands with basic land types. Have they ever left out the explicit text for nonbasic lands that still have a basic land type?

Comment: @JollyJoker Yes, the textboxes of the expedition shock lands didn't even have reminder text, only "As ~ enters the battlefield, you may pay 2 life. If you don't, ~ enters the battlefield tapped." Take a look at [Temple Garden](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=405112&type=card)

Comment: @JollyJoker It's also why [Urborg, Tomb of Yawgmoth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=457144) works, because adding the type swamp to a nonbasic land makes it able to tap for black.

Comment: Good point on Urborg. I just haven't noticed those shock lands