# Wind-Scarred Crag "Add"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I know the question is really basic but I just started magic yesterday and I have this land card that I don't understand

On [Wind-Scarred Crag](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWind-Scarred%20Crag%5d), it's written that when the card is untapped I need to add a mana fire or light, from where should I add it ? from a land already in my hand?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it means is that, when you tap Wind-Scarred Crag, you *get* one red or white mana (your choice). So it behaves like either a Mountain or a Plains<sup>[1]</sup>, depending on what you need, but with the penalty that you can't use it immediately (because it comes into play tapped). You do not need to play any additional card, you just get the mana.

<sup>[1]</sup> Although any card that specifically references Mountain or Plains will *not* affect this card, because it isn't actually either of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing Lands (cards that can often be tapped to produce mana) and mana (an intangible resource that's used to power many spells and abilities).

- A [Mountain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMountain%5d) has the following rule-granted ability:

  {T}: Add {R}.

  As such, a Mountain is a Land that produces Red mana when tapped.
- A [Wind-Scarred Crag](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWind-Scarred%20Crag%5d)

  {T}: Add {R} or {W}.

  As such, a Wind-Scarred Crag is a Land that produces Red or White mana when tapped.

("Add" means "create". "{T}", "{R}" and "{W}" refer to the Tap, Red mana and White mana symbols respectively.)

See [What is the difference between lands and mana?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/45595/2880)